# Неясное поведение std::any_cast

Tags: c++, c++17

Имеется следующий код:

```
int i = 3;
std::any a = &i;

try {
    int* ptr = std::any_cast<int>(&a);
    if (!ptr)
        ptr = std::any_cast<int*>(a);
}
catch (std::bad_cast) {
    std::cout << "Bad cast catched!\n";
}
```

Вопрос возникает насчёт данной строки:

`int* ptr = std::any_cast<int>(&a);`

Если предположить, что any хранит просто int, то я пытаюсь получить указатель на хранимые данные, т.е. указатель на int, но т.к. any хранит указатель на int, то получается, что я пытаюсь получить указатель на указатель ? Каким образом возможно приведение указателя на указатель int-а к обычному указателю на int и почему возвращается nullptr ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::any_cast` в случае попытки выполнения неправильного преобразования старается вести себя аналогично `dynamic_cast`: при передаче входного `std::any` по ссылке он выбрасывает исключение, а при передаче `std::any` по указателю он возвращает нулевой указатель.

Для выполнения успешного `std::any_cast<T>`, во всех версиях, как в ссылочных, так и в указательных, шаблонный параметр `T` должен совпадать с хранимым типом.

> почему возвращается nullptr

Ваш объект `std::any a` хранит значение типа `int *`, а вы его пытаетесь читать через `std::any_cast` как `int`. `int *` и `int` - разные типы. Так как вы используете указательную версию `std::any_cast`, несоответствие типов приводит к возвращению `nullptr`. Его вы и видите.

> я пытаюсь получить указатель на указатель ?

Да, совершенно верно, указательная версия `std::any_cast` предназначена именно для получения прямого указателя на хранимые данные. Так как ваш `a` хранит `int *`, то указательная версия `std::any_cast` предназначена для получения именно указателя на указатель `int **`. Правильный синтаксис

```
int **pptr = std::any_cast<int *>(&a);
```